# Extract information under the html code

Tags: python, html, web-crawler

This is the html code:

```
<div id="n_pnlJobResultsCount" class="jobresults_count">
    82 <span>Jobs Found</span>
</div>
```

This is my code to extract number of jobs from the above html code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


final_site = 'http://www.careerbuilder.com/jobseeker/jobs/jobresults.aspx?s_rawwords=data+scientist&s_freeloc=San+Francisco%2C+CA'
html = urllib2.urlopen(final_site).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
num_jobs_area = soup.find('div',{'class':'jobresults_count'}).encode('utf-8')
job_numbers = re.findall('\d+', num_jobs_area)[2] 
print job_numbers
```

This gives me output as 126, however I want the output 82 which is mentioned in html code as well as it displays on careerbuilder site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site you are trying to scrape returns a different result set when using Python `urllib`. If you print the `html` variable you will see that the source contains:

```
<div id="n_pnlJobResultsCount" class="jobresults_count">
    1 - 25 of 126 <span>Jobs Found</span>
</div>
```

To imitate a real browser, you can replace

```
html = urllib2.urlopen(final_site).read()
```

line with

```
req = urllib2.Request(final_site, headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' })
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

In this case you should also change

```
job_numbers = re.findall('\d+', num_jobs_area)[2]
```

line to

```
job_numbers = re.findall('\d+', num_jobs_area)[0]
```

Comment: This isn't a real *answer*. You just mentioned *what's wrong* in your *answer*, but you didn't say *how to solve it*. Please [edit] and add a solution to let your answer be a real answer, or delete it and post a comment instead.

Comment: @KevinGuan There is no *solution* because the HTML in both cases are correct, only different. I have, though, added a workaround that will result in almost the same HTML as a real browser.

Comment: That's what I meant. If you can't give a *solution*, then don't post an answer, but a comment instead. And thanks for the edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot Selcuk and Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving different data back when using `urllib`. It receives a result like this:

```
<div id="n_pnlJobResultsCount" class="jobresults_count">
    1 - 25 of 126 <span>Jobs Found</span>
</div>
```

The reason seems to be due to the user agent. You can fix this couple a couple ways.

#### Use `requests`.

```
import requests
...
html = requests.get(final_site).content
```

#### Change the user agent used by `urllib2`

```
req = urllib2.Request(final_site, headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0' })
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

---

There is also a small bug with your `job_numbers =` line. There isn't an element at the second index. Changing the line to this, solves the issue and prints the expected value though

```
job_numbers = re.findall('\d+', num_jobs_area)[0]
```